# How to find a file on the Nao V5

Tags: nao-robot, choregraphe

I wrote a script that should let the Nao walk or play a wav file when pressing a button. But the sound file never gets played and I think I am not using a correct path.

```py
def sing(note):
    try:
        path = findNotePath(note)
        soundProxy = naoqi.ALProxy("ALAudioPlayer", host, port)
        fileid = soundProxy.loadFile(path)
        soundProxy.post.playFile(fileid)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("Ton nicht abspielbar")
    print(path)

def findNotePath(note):
    path = "/home/nao/FullOctave/" + note + ".wav"
    return path
```

This is my output:

```
[W] 1685708250.183120 30208 qi.path.sdklayout: No Application was created, trying to deduce paths
[I] 1685708250.189637 30208 qimessaging.session: Session listener created on tcp://0.0.0.0:0
[I] 1685708250.794682 30208 qimessaging.transportserver: TransportServer will listen on: tcp://192.168.178.31:53942
[I] 1685708250.794682 30208 qimessaging.transportserver: TransportServer will listen on: tcp://192.168.147.1:53942
[I] 1685708250.794682 30208 qimessaging.transportserver: TransportServer will listen on: tcp://192.168.30.1:53942
[I] 1685708250.794682 30208 qimessaging.transportserver: TransportServer will listen on: tcp://127.0.0.1:53942
```

Comment: Hello! Did you get any error? Would you share it, please? Did you really upload it to `/foldername/file.wav`? I find that curious.

Comment: It's actually, for example, "FullOctave/A.wav". Maybe I said this a bit confusingly. Sorry.
I also suspect, that it might be a different problem and not a path problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. It worked, when I changed the `playFile(fileid)` to just `play(fileid)`.